# Using simpleSAMLPHP as Identity Provider for SugarCRM

Tags: php, single-sign-on, saml, sugarcrm, simplesamlphp

I installed SimpleSAMLPHP and created a SQL login source like this in the authsources.php:

```
$config = array(
    'admin' => array(
        'core:AdminPassword',
    ),
    'myLogin-sql' => array(
        'sqlauth:SQL',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=myDB',
        'username' => 'myUserName',
        'password' => 'myPasWord',
        'query' => '
            SELECT * FROM users 
            WHERE user_username = :username 
            AND user_code = (SELECT PASSWORD(:password)) 
            AND user_active=1',
    ),
);
```

Then I specified the Identification Provider in saml20-idp-hosted.php to use my source like this:

```
$metadata['__DYNAMIC:1__'] = array(
    'host' => '__DEFAULT__',
    'privatekey' => 'myWebiste.com.pem',
    'certificate' => 'myWebsite.com.crt',
    'auth' => 'myLogin-sql',
};
```

The query definitely work so I know that is not the problem.  Yet when I turn it on in sugarCRM, it say unable to find the binder:

```
SimpleSAML_Error_Error: UNHANDLEDEXCEPTION
Backtrace:
1 /home/public_html/sso/www/_include.php:37 (SimpleSAML_exception_handler)
0 [builtin] (N/A)
Caused by: Exception: Unable to find the current binding.
Backtrace:
2 /home/public_html/sso/vendor/simplesamlphp/saml2/src/SAML2/Binding.php:97 (SAML2_Binding::getCurrentBinding)
1 /home/public_html/sso/modules/saml/lib/IdP/SAML2.php:292 (sspmod_saml_IdP_SAML2::receiveAuthnRequest)
0 /home/public_html/sso/www/saml2/idp/SSOService.php:18 (N/A)
```

What am I doing wrong?

PS:  You can try it using the link [here](http://mdina.ca/sso/www/saml2/idp/SSOService.php)

Comment: Something is wrong at your simpleSAMLphp settings.

When I access simpleSAMLphp authentication page [1] I don't see the 'myLogin-sql' that you described in your example, instead a 'default-sp' 

Are you using the same simpleSAMLphp instance as IdP and SP?

[1] https://mdina.ca/sso/www/module.php/core/authenticate.php

Comment: What's the difference between IdP and SP?  I thought I setup an IdP to connect to my local database, then sugarCRM can connect to that.  What would SP do?

Comment: You deployed an IdP that is using sugarCRM database as the authentication source. Now you need to enable a SP (to protect the sugarCRM), and connect this SP with the IdP.  Read this similar case: https://github.com/pitbulk/tiki-saml/blob/master/doc/tiki_wiki_as_idp.rst